# How to identify the root npm package from within a dependency

Tags: node.js, npm

I am currently writing a small package that is intended to be used as a dev dependency in the root package of a project. It's goal is to automatically configure git pre-commit hooks for automatic code linting of JS code. When the package is installed as a dependency of another package (using the npm installation lifecycle hooks), it drops a `pre-commit` script in the `.git/hooks` directory of the Git repository. This script calls out to `npm` and runs a configurable linting action, so that linting is performed every time a commit is made.

The one missing piece to the puzzle is supporting multiple root npm packages in a monorepo, which means I can't assume that the `npm` command can be run from the root of the repository. Instead, I need to configure my `pre-commit` hook to set the working directory of the `npm` command to the location of the root package that installed my package as a dependency.

During runtime, npm doesn't provide a lot of information to dependencies about the parent package that installed it. All of the `npm_...` environment variables that are set during the execution of my package's installation lifecycle hook all have to do with my package. The only thing that seems viable is the `INIT_CWD` environment variable, but I'm not sure what it's behavior is.

Is there a way to identify the root project location?